# Tile from selection does not repeat the selection using filters → map → tile

Tags: gimp

In Gimp I created an image which supposed to be a part of a 80 x 80 px tile set,
the image size is 16 x 16 pixels. 
I try to use the map → tile filter as every one is suggesting, but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong? It just don't create the tiles.

[image]

Comment: `Filer>Map>Tile` uses your whole input image, so that image should be the size of a single tile, and the image dimensions are the dimensions of the image your create by tiling it. But when you know the "clipboard pattern"  trick or the Symmetry painting in 2.10, you don't really need that filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Old-style method:

- Select the tile with the rectangle selection, copy selection to clipboard
- Start the bucket-fill tool, set it to "Pattern Fill" mode
- Click the pattern preview icon, and in the list of patterns, select the fist one (top left corner) which should be your tile (and named `clipboard image`)
- Bucket-fill.

#### Gimp 2.10 method for the next time:

- `Windows>Dockable dialogs>Symmetry painting`
- Set Symmetry to `Tiling`
- Set the `Interval` values to your tile size
- While you paint, the pattern in repeated over the layer